# Executing a test on Headless (HtmlUnitDriver) mode, passes on Eclipse IDE but fails when executed in JMeter

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, htmlunit, headless

I have a simple java-selenium-maven script written in Eclipse IDE which I have exported in a JAR file and I tried to execute from JMeter.

I have two versions of this script, one is with normal `ChromeDriver` and the other one is headless and it uses the `HtmlUnitDriver`.

Here is the second one as it is the one that misbehaves:

```
package testing1;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class NewTestHeadless {
      @Test
      public void testGoogleSearch() throws InterruptedException {
          WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
          Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something! 
          WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
          searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
          searchBox.submit();
          Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
          driver.quit();
      }
      
      @Before
      public void beforeT() {
          System.out.println("BEFOREEEE");
      }
      
      @After
      public void afterT() {
          System.out.println("AFTEERRRR");
      }
      
}
```

This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>selenium.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>testing-example-selenium</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>testing</name>
  
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And this is the structure of my project in Eclipse IDE

[image]

Here is how i exported to JAR file

[image]

I have put this file under `apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\junit` and I can see correctly in JUnit Request Samplers the classes and methods from that script

[image]

When i execute in Eclipse, both test (headless + chrome) passes but when i execute from JMeter, the headless one fails

Any ideas of what might be the problem?

This is the sampler response in the Results Tree listener and the response is empty:

```
Thread Name:Scenario 27 - Selenium JUnit 5-1
Sample Start:2020-08-25 12:26:16 EEST
Load time:980
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:0
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:0
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:1000
Response message:


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: windows-1252
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one important step: your .jar file has only your code and doesn't contain `htmlunit-driver`, `selenium-java`, etc. so my expectation is that if you look into [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) you will see that JMeter cannot find Selenium-related classes.

Quick and dirty solution would be executing [`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` command](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) and once it is done copy everything from `target/dependencies` folder of your project to the "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (or other place in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))

After restart you should see your test working.

A better option would be [using Maven Shade plugin for creating a "uber jar"](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) containing everyting which is needed for running your test

And last but not the least you may find [JMeter WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) much easier to use

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fact that the non headless selenium runs in jmeter without a problem it just means that i moved only some of the things that were needed?
Is there any way i can get in jmeter some more detailed logs when i execute selenium tests in case something fails?